# how to switch from 64 bit python 2.7 to 32 bit python 2.7 on mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I need to switch from 64 bit python to 32 bit, in order to run py-game. because py-game only comes in 32 bit version and does not come in 64 bit. so i either have to be able to switch it from 64 to 32 or uninstall the 64 and install the 32. and on that note i have no idea how to do either of them.

thanks

Comment: I would guess that [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) might help, but I don't know specifics.

Comment: You definitely don't want to uninstall the 64bit version, that will break anything on your computer that runs on python and assumed you had the default 64bit install. Try just installing the [32bit version](https://www.python.org/download) and then setting your python path appropriately in your pygame scripts.

Comment: Do you have an error message which says that Python 32 bit doesn't run? Windows 64 bits can run 32 and 64 bits program, is it different on Max OS X?

Answer (score 1):

Install the 32-bit version here:

https://www.python.org/download/

I don't recommend uninstalling the 64 bit version as it could potentially break some programs in your computer.

But should you want to follow through (and again, I don't recommend), follow this tutorial here:
http://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/installing_python_osx/

Basic overview (please look at guide for the complete safer way to do this):

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Python 2.7"
```

This will remove python from your system. And to furthermore complete, find the related-python links in: /usr/local/bin use `ls` and `rm -rf`to delete them.